# Git plugins fails to start Jenkins 2.346.2 running on Tomcat 10.0.22 on Linux server

Tags: jenkins, tomcat, jenkins-plugins, tomcat10

I'm running apache tomcat 10.0.22 on a Linux server. I have deployed Jenkins 2.346.2 on the tomcat server. However, on installing git-server, git-client plugins from Jenkins plugins manager, Jenkins fails to reload with the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.onLoaded(GitSCM.java:2162)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:109)
Caused: java.lang.Error
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:115)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder$TaskImpl.run(TaskMethodFinder.java:185)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:305)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1158)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:222)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:121)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:291)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:49)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1193)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:983)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:86)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:82)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:247)
Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:264)
```

On deleting the git-server.jpi and git-client-jpi from Jenkins plugins directory, this issue gets fixed.

Is there a way to install git-server and git-client plugins in Jenkins 2.346.2?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What errors do you see?

Comment: @ycr I have updated the error message in the post. Thank you.